# wso2 datamapper hangs WSO2 developer studio when gives large json file as input

Tags: json, eclipse, ide, wso2

I have to consume a rest service which returns a json in response.
From that json response I need to create another json format , which will be output of my service.

In data mapper , I define input as json, and provide sample json (response from service I need to consume) as  example. This json is quite big (some 1200 lines).
As soon as I upload json example eclipse hangs for ever.

I tried increasing maxPermsize of eclipse but no use.
I am using developer studio on Eclipse Mars.

Please guide me: I tried using eclipse neon but wso2 developer studio tab did not  appear in eclipse after installing plugins.
Maybe eclipse neon does  not support WSO2.
I also downloaded wso2 developer studio pre-instaled in eclipse luna. But data mapper was missing in palette there.

What can I try to get past this issue?

Comment: Can your sample message size be reduced? For example, if it contains an array of elements just put 2 or 3 elements instead of the complete array.

Comment: Thanks Palle, I could reduced the size by only little , now also the eclipse gets hanged. For other services which I need to build , the output from service to be consumed is suppose to be even bigger in size. Thanks for above option it helped a bit, more suggestions required.